# Problems when trying to compile a Hello World with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having problems when trying to compile the following code:

[image]

I first tried compiling with this code:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

it works as it should. Now, if I try to replace the class name for any other name, it won't work anymore, as it seems to always look after HelloWorldApp. I made sure the file is being saved and so, I even reopened Eclipse. Still the same error. Maybe this is a common problem, with a small work-around?

Thanks

---

edit: I see what you guys mean, but why does it work when I have the file name as "Main.java" and a class name of "HelloWorldApp" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rename your .java file to match the class name.

Eclipse will rename your **.java** file to match your class name automatically if you use its refactoring support. Right click on the class name, hover over *Refactor*, and select the *Rename* option. Now when you rename your class, Eclipse will automatically rename your **.java** file to match.

Comment: ...or select the classname (or just put cursor in it) in sourcecode and hit `Alt+Shift+R`.

Comment: That's only necessary for public classes, though. Package-private classes (not marked either public or private) can be named anything.

Comment: @mmyers - you are right, didn't notice it was default scoped. Javac should have no problem producing *FooBar.class* from *HellowWorldApp.java*. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work; I'm able to change (default-scoped) class names at will and they run fine in STS 2.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

This is how Java works. Class must have the same name as the file. So the filename for the class MyApp, must be MyApp.java

Answer (score 1):

Rename main as HelloWorldApp so that your app becomes HelloWorldApp.java.

Comment: I see your point, but if I keep the current file name (Main.java), it will work with a class name of HelloWorldApp!

Answer (score 0):

When changing the name of your class use the REFACTOR option - If you try to edit the name manually yourself the Eclipse Project loses track of your objects.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. Look in the right corner, you'll see it is updating correctly my class outline.

Comment: Looking at the tab document - it reads "Main.java" If you had used Refactor properly it should be reading "HelloWfor.java"